# Spark runs out of memory without caching

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I'm really struggling to understand why am running out of Memory while running a Spark job. I loaded my RDD from database and am not caching the RDDs, yet the job still fails missing an output location.

This is just too crazy...any idea what I need to do to fix this issue ?

Am running on a standalone cluster

```
Alive Workers: 5
Cores in use: 200 Total, 200 Used
Memory in use: 782.0 GB Total, 700.0 GB Used
```

Exceptions

```
org.apache.spark.shuffle.MetadataFetchFailedException: Missing an output location for shuffle 4
    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$MapOutputTracker$$convertMapStatuses$2.apply(MapOutputTracker.scala:695)
    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$MapOutputTracker$$convertMapStatuses$2.apply(MapOutputTracker.scala:691)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker$.org$apache$spark$MapOutputTracker$$convertMapStatuses(MapOutputTracker.scala:691)
    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker.getMapSizesByExecutorId(MapOutputTracker.scala:145)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.BlockStoreShuffleReader.read(BlockStoreShuffleReader.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.CoGroupedRDD$$anonfun$compute$2.apply(CoGroupedRDD.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.CoGroupedRDD$$anonfun$compute$2.apply(CoGroupedRDD.scala:137)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.CoGroupedRDD.compute(CoGroupedRDD.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Decent crystal balls are not common these days so I would really suggest you reduce the problem to a [mcve] and after that show us your code. Since it looks like you're using `coGroup` or operation which is based on it is good place to start looking for the culprit.

Comment: yeah...I have a very simple gist of the code here, if you could take a look at it.https://gist.github.com/mavencode01/686398f1d5f22cc55e5563fcbb1813ec

Comment: Well, after quick glance a) This looks more like a job for message passing Pregel b) You effectively perform a lot of `joins` on RDDs  which are twice as bad as `groupByKey` (this is probably where it fails). Dataset could be slightly more gracious here c) Finally you perform `groupBy` which can result in further issues.

Comment: @zero323: a) I donno if I have the time to implement connected component clustering using Pregel...will have to check it out. b) I it fails here `subtract at RecursivePostMerge.scala:64`... Exception: org.apache.spark.shuffle.MetadataFetchFailedException: Missing an output location for shuffle 4. c) the group by is an easy fix...is not failing yet for that.

Comment: GraphX provides connected components out of the box, doesn't it? `groupBy` may be easy to fix, `joins` not so much.

Comment: @zero323 I already implemented it with Graphx(Connected component)  by  modelling my hierarchical dataset as Vertices and Edges, however, I lost some fields joining the CC to the vertices. Don't know how to explain it...but it partially solve the problem.